# Autowired in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

i've asked this before but never had any answer that made sense.

if ServiceClass is annotated with `@Service` in java spring i can do

```
@Autowired
private ServiceClass serviceClass;
```

or better yet

```
private final ServiceClass serviceClass;

public userManagementClass(ServiceClass serviceClass) {
        this.serviceClass = serviceClass;
    }
```

Then i changed to kotlin and..

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var addressRepository: AddressRepository
```

where AddressRepository is annotated with `@Repository` is okey but now the first one, ServiceClass with `@Service`

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var serviceClass: ServiceClass
```

and

```
@Autowired constructor(
      private val serviceClass: ServiceClass
)
```

both give error `No beans of type found`
Do i now need a constructor for my services in kotlin or what?

I've read many articles titled like "understanding kotlin lateinit" and what not, but i think im still missing some core ideas since none of them make any goddamn sense... Kotlin documentation is okey, but only for concepts you already know.. otherwise it also is very confusing.

**EDIT** appears that giving ServiceClass a constructor didnt do anything either

Comment: Does your component scan cover  and register `ServiceClass`?

Comment: "i've asked this before" please link to the previous questions, and describe exactly what about the answers that didn't make sense.

Comment: Why not use constructor DI ?

Comment: @AndyTurner there is no answer to link.

Comment: @YassinHajaj i dont know, there is no bean type of ServiceClass is what intelliJ keeps telling me, thats the question

Comment: @Clomez which link? You say that you never had an answer *that made sense*. If you don't tell us what didn't make sense, you might get another answer in the same terms.

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin (and in Java I think) you can inject your dependencies in the constructor like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class ServiceClass constructor(
    private val repository: AddressRepository
) {
    // Do stuff here
}

@Repository
class AddressRepository
```

this is the same that:

```
@Service
class ServiceClass {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var repository: AddressRepository

    // Do stuff here
}

@Repository
class AddressRepository
```

but it allow you to make unit tests without the need of a Spring Context (@SpringBootTest).

Then you can inject your service in another the same way

```
@Service
class OtherService constructor(
    private val service: ServiceClass
) {
    // Other stuff here
}
```

There's no bean problem with this code for me. (IntelliJ 2019.1.1)

Comment: yeah, thats nice. but the problem is that there is no bean type of ServiceClass available, i can inject repository however i want, it seems.